# using url_for in a generated html

Tags: flask

i'm working with a flask to make a dashborard, in my project i have a script inside the flask app that generates the html code.
and my question is how to use url_for to create the dynamic routing is this case, here is my code:

```
rec+='<td><a href="url_for(case,id='+row['ID']+'" id="'+str(row['ID'])+'" >More</a></td>'
```

Any ideas how to make it work and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `{{ }}` enclose the `url_for` statement.

```
rec += '<td><a href="{{ url_for(case, id=' + str(row['ID']) + ') }}">More</a></td>'
```

or use format string(more readable):

```
rec += '<td><a href="{{ url_for(case, id={}) }}">More</a></td>'.format(row['ID'])
```

Comment: both codes raise the same error: /%7B%7B%20url_for(case,%20id=0)%20%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404